# Windows 10: xdebug not stopping with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows, apache, xdebug

httpd.conf set listen:9080 (listen 80 would not work with windows 10 visual studio is somehow stopping it working.)
so url that works is `http://localhost:9080/project2`

php.ini settings appeared correctly in phpinfo()

    `[xdebug]
    xdebug.remote_enable=On
    xdebug.remote_autostart=On
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_host=localhost:9080
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    xdebug.profiler_enable = off
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
    xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
    xdebug.show_local_vars=0`

and set in eclipse

preferences -> php -> Servers -> edit

Base URL: `http://localhost:9080`

Local Web Root : `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

Servers -> What is  path mapping?

Path on Server ? `http://localhost:9080/project2`

Local Path ?  `C:\Apache24\htdocs\project2`

Set PHP Executables as follows:

Executable Path: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

php.ini: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini`

Debug -> Run Configurations -> Debugger -> Configure

Accept Remote Session: tried localhost and prompt

Tried in Chrome and Opera they both run without stopping.
Can debug by printing to page though would like to use debugger.

Cannot think of any other reason debug set and green in chrome. Tried disabling it and selecting debug again.

Please reply soon.